# Mass update meta titles for multi store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, meta-tags

I want to mass update the meta titles for all products, and I have been able to update the the default/global for the products with MAGMI with the column title `meta_title`

But I want to have different meta titles for different store views.Its seems that the store view meta titles are stored in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table but I can't see how this is linked back to the product sku.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: i believe we can import meta title different for different stores

Comment: do you know how?

Comment: I would achieve this from exporting products with `sku` and `meta-title` and then editing relevant field then importing. Import/export is available from `System > Import/Export > Data Flow Profiles`.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/79jzmw you need to change store values here. put sku and different meta titles and try. I never tried this. But i am sure, its achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `System > Import/Export` I uploaded a csv in this format

```
sku  _store  meta_title
sku1         Default meta title
     store 1 Store 1 meta title
sku2         Default meta title
     store 2 Store 2 meta title
```

leave to first _store cell blank to set default value (you have to do this)
Leave the 2nd line sku cell blank

This format working for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple script that updates the meta title for one product in one store view based on the SKU. You can create a CSV file or any other parsable format and use this script in a loop to update your meta titles

```
$sku = '12345';
$storeId = 2;
$metaTitle = 'Updated meta title';
$id = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if ($id) {
     Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
         array($id),
         array('meta_title' => $metaTitle),
         $storeId
     );
}
```

Setting `0` (zero) for `$storeId` means that the default values will be updated.

Comment: nice solution though.. (y)

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_store_column

Go through above link. It explains, how we can import to different stores. Inspire from it. Good luck.